# Is = an operator, a statement, or a delimiter?

Tags: python, delimiter, assignment-operator

See [Is assignment an operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46180894/13595466) The answer states:

> An assignment is always a statement in Python.

Now, see this link of [Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). In that, see the **Note** section (emphasis mine):

> Note: If the object is a class instance and the attribute reference occurs on both sides of the **assignment operator**, the right-hand side expression, a.x can access either an instance attribute or (if no instance attribute exists) a class attribute.

Here the term *"assignment operator"* is used. Now, the [list of operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) in the official documentation of Python does not contain an assignment operator, but `=` is contained in the *Delimiters* section.

Is assignment an operator, a statement, or a delimiter?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? Also, realistically, does it matter? `=` is a delimiter *in* a statement, so your options aren't actually mutually exclusive.

Comment: Assignments involving the `=` character can only occur in statements. So it's an assignment statement. A statement of course consists of multiple parts. So how do you call the `=` character within the assignment statement? Syntactically *delimiter* is correct, but colloquially "operator" is more understood. Probably the author of that note slipped into a colloquialism there.

Comment: We should call `:=` *the* assignment operator. Or walrus.

Comment: @timgeb Now you're just asking for mass confusion. :P

Comment: Do people even use the walrus operator?

Comment: @bug_spray I don't think it will be available until Python 3.9.  Hard to use something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Mark You think wrong. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions

Comment: @deceze thanks for the correction.  So it's been available for 7 months.