# Why am I getting a syntax error when using the >>= operator?

Tags: python, parsec

**Note:** I am importing the [*parsec* library](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py), which [*overloads* the `>>=` (i.e. - `__irshift()__`) operator](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/blob/3b7daa0b93483d6de5817fd445664aeff2f5721a/src/parsec/__init__.py#L285).

The following Python code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

# irshift_debug.py

from parsec import *

def id(x):
    """Identity parser."""
    return string("").result(x)

testp = digit() >>= id

print(testp.parse("5"))
```

yields:

```
$ ./irshift_debug.py
  File "./irshift_debug.py", line 9
    testp = digit() >>= id
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But, if I change the offending line to:

```py
testp = digit().bind(id)
```

then I get:

```
$ ./irshift_debug.py
5
```

as expected.

I thought that `>>=` was the infix equivalent of `bind()`;
is that incorrect?

Comment: >> in python is a bit operator... what are u trying to do exactly?

Comment: @SrishruthikAlle, I'm trying to use the infix operator that is a shortcut for the bind() function in the parsec library.

Comment: Python is not C++: Assignment is not an operator and therefore has no resulting value. Note that limited support for an assignment expression was added to Python 3.8 in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Comment: “bind” is the name of `>>=` in Haskell, but it’s not a Python operator.

Comment: @Ry-, the (>>=) operator gets overloaded in the parsec library. Please, see the newly added note at the top of the original question.

Comment: `>>=` isn't an operator; it's part of the syntax for augmented assignments. It can only be used in a *statement*, never in an *expression*.

Comment: The fact that you get a  syntax error is a hint that whatever you've done wrong is independent of the definition of any dunder method, because Python hasn't even gotten to the point where dunder methods are relevant. The parser couldn't even generate a syntax tree, let alone one that the code generator can use to produce something that needs to find the appropriate definition of a dunder method to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a design mistake.

I have turned to use `>=` as the operator for `bind()` and deprecated `>>=`. A new release of parsec.py has been upload to pypi.

Answer (score 4):

Because `>>=` is a statement, not an expression. It doesn't evaluate to a result that can be assigned to `testp`.

Perhaps you were looking for this?

```
testp = digit >> id
```

Comment: More properly, `>>=` is what is called an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I have used neither Parsec nor Haskell, so I can't speak to the intended use in the context of this library. However, I believe the main root of your confusion here is that [augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) work differently than operators, and therefore [reimplementing them](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#object.__iadd__) works [slightly differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546707/12975140) as well. (Unlike in C and many other languages, [assignment is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180894/is-assignment-an-operator-in-python) in Python.)

So you've seen this code:

```
def __irshift__(self, other):
    '''Implements the `(>>=)` operator, means `bind`.'''
    return self.bind(other)
```

What isn't immediately obvious is that, because this is overriding augmented assignment, not an operator, the returned value is used to reassign the original item on the left. In other words, this code:

```
a >>= b
```

is *not* the same as simply:

```
a.bind(b)
```

Instead, it is (essentially) equivalent to:

```
a = a.bind(b)
```

As mentioned in [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70628666/12975140), the resulting assignment is a statement, not an expression, and can't ultimately return a value at all (not even `None`). The right half of an assignment statement has to be an expression; it can't be another assignment statement<sup>1</sup>. Just as in Python you can't do things like<sup>2</sup>:

```
a = b += c
```

So you also can't do:

```
a = b >>= c
```

...even when you've reimplemented `>>=`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The only partial exception is the recently added [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), but it is (intentionally) limited in use, and won't help you here.

<sup>2</sup> On the other hand, "[chained assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346517/12975140)", e.g. `a = b = c`, *does* work. It's something of a special case, in that it's not simply a series of operators that return their values; `a = (b = c)` is still a syntax error. Instead, it's all parsed as one assignment statement.